# Adding seconds to hr:min timestamp in R

Tags: r, string, timestamp

I want to complete a time stamp in an R dataframe. The current timestamp is missing seconds, hh:mm, but it needs to be hh:mm:ss. In this case I just need to add ":00" to all the timestamps.

Timestamps looks like this `"10:25" "10:29"  "11:32"`

But it needs to be `"10:25:00"  "10:29:00"  "11:32:00"`

I have tried the following, but nothing is being added.

```
gsub("(:dd)$","\\1:00",test$`TIME`)
gsub(" .*$", "\\1",test$`TIME`)
gsub("dd$", ":00",test$`TIME`)
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason for ```test$`TIME```? Can't we just do `test$TIME`?

Comment: test$TIME is fine. I was using the quotes because I have several other variables with spaces, such as test$'CURRENT DATE'

Comment: Then use the `make.names` function in order to make them valid variable names.

Comment: Thanks David, I was not aware of the 'make.names' function.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
sub('^(\\d+:\\d+)$', '\\1:00', v1)
#[1] "10:25:00" "10:29:00" "11:32:00" "10:42:20" "11:22:00" "10:22:30" ""
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('10:25', '10:29', '11:32', '10:42:20', '11:22', '10:22:30', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think this is simple..

```
time <- "14:30"

# using paste0
paste0(time, ":00")
```

Comment: Sometimes the timestamp is emty. It will then look like :00. I only want to add seconds with existing timestamps that looks like "hh:mm"

Comment: The filter by non empty strings

Comment: This worked to when checking for emty strings. The sulution by akrun was even more flexible. Thanks.